# angular 2 on form submit ERROR TypeError: _co.onSubmit is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am using  angular 2 application. on form submit I am getting this error:

> ```
> TypeError: _co.onSubmit is not a function
> ```

Here is a screenshot of the full error:

[image]

My form:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Create User</button>
```

My `userComponent.ts`:

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I too have same error this error occurs when the name of the methods called in an event not matched with the template declaration and inside the class
In my case the template was

```
<form class="container" #userRegistrationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(userRegistrationForm)">
```

and my component.ts file

```
       onSubmit(form:NgForm){
     this.userService.registerUser(form.value)
     .subscribe((data:any)=>{
       if(data.Succeeded==true)
       this.resetForm(form);
     });
   }
```

After changing `onSubmit` to `OnSubmit`in my component.ts file

I was able to resolve this error